# Proving convegence of sequence

Tags: convergence-divergence, absolute-convergence

How do I prove

$w_{k+1} = \frac{-(2 (3 - 4 e + 2 e^2) g )}{(-5 + 4 e)} \times w_k$

converges to $0$ over $k\rightarrow \infty$ and say $w_0=1$

Possible bounds are: $0<e<1$ and $0<g<1$.

Also $e$ is just another variable, not Euler number

Comment: Series or sequence ?

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I want to prove that any values of coefficient of $a_k$ will eventually make $a_{k+1}$ converge to zero with infinite number of multiplications or iterative calculation of $a_{k+1}$.

Comment: So you are interesting of the convergence of the *sequence* $a_k$, not the series ? Your title mentions the word series.

Comment: Yeah ...sorry will fix that

Comment: What is general approach for this?

Comment: What is $e$ and $g$?  "*Wolfram says so*" that the sequence converges *when $g=0$*... but of course... if $g=0$ you have $a_k=0$ for all $k>0$ so that is hardly interesting

Comment: Looking at this in greater detail... isn't every term zero regardless what $e,g$ are?  You have $a_1 = \lambda \cdot 0 \cdot a_0=0$ where $\lambda=\frac{-2(3-4e+2e^2)g}{(-5+4e)}$ and so $a_2 = \lambda \cdot 1 \cdot a_1 = \lambda \cdot 1\cdot 0 = 0$... and by induction you see everything is zero from then on... Are you certain you have no typos in what you wrote?  It seems a very silly question otherwise...

Comment: Ok I definitely made mistake there. I fixed it. Now I dont know I was looking at wolfram in right direction.

Comment: Now, this is just a geometric sequence... Just see if the ratio is $|.|>1$ or $|.|<1$.

Comment: Yeah I know I have to prove coefficient of $w_k<1$ for $w_k$ to converge to zero. But unable to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $g=0.9$ and $e=0.1$, then $$\left| \frac{-(2 (3 - 4 e + 2 e^2) g )}{(-5 + 4 e)}\right| >1$$

So the sequence diverges.

Comment: seems that I have messed up with this